# FTPClient path/directory change. Multiple directories in single FTPClient InputStream connect. Unknown parser type: "/Path" is current directory

Tags: java, directory, ftp, ftp-client, cd

FTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory & changeToParentDirectory(). How to change directory in ftpCient. In explorer the ftp path looks like this `ftp://192.168.10.20`. once entering this, I can see folders `COMPLETED, FAILURE and QRCODEGENERATE`. In my java code first I'm entering inside `FAILURE` folder and getting the respective file. And this process is successfully done. After getting it I want to enter into `COMPLETED` folder, I mean the directory path has to be changed like this `/FAILURE` to `COMPLETED` but it's getting error. I shared the Console error at the bottom.

I can get the value if I close the connection and open again. But I dont want to do like that. I want to change the directory with out closing the connection.

1.First I'm getting into `FAILURE` and I'm accessing a file and its contents.

2.Then I'm going back to `COMPLETED` and I want to access the files and its contents.

Here is my JAVA code

```
InputStream is = null;
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
strDir= "FAILURE";
ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory();
String[] ftpList=ftpClient.listNames();
//Here I'm listing the folders present in parent directory
for(int i =0; i<ftpList.length;i++)
{
    String ftpFilsList=ftpList[i];
    System.out.println(".........::::::::::"+ftpFilsList);
}

//getting into Failure Folder and fetching file

ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory()+strDir);
System.out.println("prnt#WorkingDir"+ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
is =ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filename+".json");

int i=0;
String valuesinside="";
while((i = is.read())!=-1)
{
    //valuesinside+=valuesinside+i;
    char c = (char)i;
    valuesinside+=Character.toString(c);
    ftpfilelist=valuesinside;
}
//Successfully Fetched file and its contents
                
//change the directory to COMPLETED Folder
                
String strFullFileName = "";
File fileJson=null;
int intfilecount=00;
String strFileCount="";
strDir = "COMPLETED";
                
ftpClient.changeToParentDirectory();//To go back to previos directory
System.out.println("PARENRT+++++:::::"+ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());//This shows null
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(strDir);
ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory();
System.out.println("COMPLETED+++++:::::"+ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());//Shows "/COMPLETED" in the console. but not getting the files.
FTPFile[] fileJsonReader=ftpClient.listFiles(ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory()); 
for(FTPFile ftpFile:fileJsonReader)
{
    String strJsonFileName=null;
    strJsonFileName=ftpFile.getName();
    System.out.println("strJsonFileName:::+++++"+strJsonFileName);
    String strBillNoFile=strJsonFileName.substring(0, strJsonFileName.lastIndexOf("-"));//-01
    System.out.println("strBillNoFile+++++::::::"+strBillNoFile);
    strBillNoFile=strBillNoFile+".json";
    System.out.println("strBillNoFile:::::+++++"+strBillNoFile);
    if(strBillNoFile.equalsIgnoreCase(filename.getName()))
    {
        
        intfilecount=intfilecount+1;
    }
 }
```

In console I'm getting error like this. You can see the list of folders shown first.

```
.....................:::::::::::::::COMPLETED
.......................:::::::::::::::FAILURE
.......................:::::::::::::::QRCODEGENERATE
prnt#WorkingDir/FAILURE
PARENT+++++:::::::null
COMPLETED+++++:::::/COMPLETED
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ParserInitializationException: Unknown parser type: "/COMPLETED" is current directory.
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.createFileEntryParser(DefaultFTPFileEntryParserFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:2263)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2046)
    at com.restService.FtpJson.FTPAuthJSONReader(FtpJson.java:130)
    at com.restService.JsonFailCompleted.getMessage(JsonFailCompleted.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:209)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:610)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

### Solution

-----Just closed the inputStream `is.close()` and `Boolean result = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();`

### Throws nullPointerException in InputStream

`is =ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filename+".json");` here if the folder doesn't have the requested file name, it throws NullPointerException. How to handle it without changing `retrieveFileStream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

It looks like the issue is caused because you use this method `retrieveFileStream();`, which needs some extra processes and the server either disconnects or behaves oddly once it is finished. Here is the key part information from the [api referance](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/):

> retrieveFileStream - Returns an InputStream from which a named file from
> the server can be read. If the current file type is ASCII, the
> returned InputStream will convert line separators in the file to the
> local representation. You **must close the InputStream when you finish**
> reading from it. The InputStream itself will take care of **closing the**
> **parent data connection socket upon being closed**.
>
> **To finalize the file transfer you must call completePendingCommand** and
> check its return value to verify success. If this is not done,
> subsequent commands may behave unexpectedly.

So you need to close the steam `is.close();` then use `ftpClient.completePendingCommand();`. Once this is done, you can check if the connection is still alive `if(ftp.isConnected() == true){...}` and if not then you can reconnect `ftp.connect(...);` then move onto your next command to change the working directory.

```
//Open the stream
is =ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filename+".json");

//Process the stream data
int i=0;
String valuesinside="";
while((i = is.read())!=-1)
{
    //valuesinside+=valuesinside+i;
    char c = (char)i;
    valuesinside+=Character.toString(c);
    ftpfilelist=valuesinside;
}

//Close the stream and complete the command
is.close();
Boolean result = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

//check if connection is alive
if(ftp.isConnected() == false){
    //reconnect here with your server details
    //...
}

//Now move onto the next commands
ftpClient.changeToParentDirectory();/
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("COMPLETED");
System.out.println("PARENRT+++++:::::"+ftpClient.printWorkingDirectory());
```

Alternatly you could use a different method where you manage the stream manually rather than using the API, for example you could do `retrieveFile(fileName, outputStream);`.

### The ParserInitializationException error:

If you are interested more about other reasons why the error happens then see here at the apache [FTPClient docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles-java.lang.String-):

> ParserInitializationException - Thrown if the parserKey parameter
> cannot be resolved by the selected parser factory. In the
> DefaultFTPEntryParserFactory, this will happen when parserKey is
> neither the fully qualified class name of a class implementing the
> interface org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileEntryParser nor a string
> containing one of the recognized keys mapping to such a parser or if
> class loader security issues prevent its being loaded.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I have made. This time I clearly elaborated and explained. I'm Trying to go back from the current folder and get into another folder.

Comment: Yes, one way to do that is to use an absolute path as shown in my answer. Your code looks like you successfully navigate to the completed folder, but then you also use an incorrect relative path. Just try editing the one line to not provide an additional path `ftpClient.listFiles();`

Comment: Should I give `strDir` in the parameter `ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(strDir);` instead of  `absoluteDirectoryPath`?

Comment: Yes, you can use it there. Once you have used that command then other commands don't need the path because they will use the current working directory by default.

Comment: Now game changed, I did as you said, but its showing `FAILURE` in completed.
`...............:::::::::::::::::::COMPLETED
...............:::::::::::::::::::FAILURE
...............:::::::::::::::::::QRCODEGENERATE
prnt#WorkingDir/FAILURE
COMPLETED+++++:::::/FAILURE
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.parser.ParserInitializationException: Unknown parser type: "/FAILURE" is current directory.`

Comment: Very interesting. What happens if you enter the COMPLETED folder first, instead of the FAILURE folder? If that works, then we know that it is not a security/permission issue

Comment: Yes it works if I set the COMPLETED folder first. And also I did this way, closed the connection like this `ftpClient.logout();`
 `ftpClient.disconnect();` and opened again. Its getting into COMPLETED folder. But without closing how can I get into it?

Comment: I just noticed that you were using `retrieveFileStream()` rather than `retrieveFile()`, we need to do a few extra things to make sure it works correctly. I have updated my answer with details.

Comment: This worked. After closing the InputStream `is.close()`. I can go into another folder. Thanks for helping bro. Here comes 50 rep ;-)

Comment: Here I'm facing new error. could you help me to solve it. I explained in the bottom of the question. `Throws nullpointerexception`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223870/discussion-between-sorifiend-and-sarath69kumar).